# Why is GitHub markdown not parsing this reference?

Tags: github, markdown

I'm trying to reference a commit within my `README.md` to note a change in project format.  The [Writing on GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/writing-on-github/#references) article says that:

> Certain references are auto-linked:
>
> - SHA: a5c3785ed8d6a35868bc169f07e40e889087fd2e
>
> ...
>
> becomes
>
> SHA: [a5c3785](https://github.com/jlord/sheetsee.js/commit/a5c3785ed8d6a35868bc169f07e40e889087fd2e)

I am trying to accomplish this same effect.  However, I'm not sure if I am doing it correctly.  In my `README.md`, I have tried to use just the plain `SHA` string, as well as all the other mentioned auto-parsed reference structures but none of them turn into a link to the commit.

The commit with the attempted reference can be found: [`README.md`](https://github.com/zero298/java-file-hash-checker/blob/d42eb44b3c20f5ab7f1f640beb25b522953d0af4/README.md)

What am I doing incorrectly and how can I get the reference to automatically parse?  Or should I just give in and make the link manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That article is specifically for

> Issues, comments, and pull request descriptions

In your `README.md` you'll have to create the link manually, e.g.

```
[f3d15103e177b27d3e5d0533de6ca77e966fb4ba](https://github.com/zero298/java-file-hash-checker/commit/f3d15103e177b27d3e5d0533de6ca77e966fb4ba)

or

[f3d1510][1]

[1]: https://github.com/zero298/java-file-hash-checker/commit/f3d15103e177b27d3e5d0533de6ca77e966fb4ba
```